# Undefined getException method while handling exception in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony5

I created an exception class as follows:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use function strpos;

final class HTTPExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if (! ($exception instanceof HttpException) || strpos($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), '/api/') === false) {
            return;
        }

        $response = new JsonResponse(['error' => $exception->getMessage()]);
        $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

I have added following to my `services.yaml` file:

```
 App\Exception\HTTPExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

But I am getting error:

`Attempted to call an undefined method named "getException" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent".`

Comment: Shouldn't you call `$event->getThrowable()` ?

Comment: So can't you simply open the `ExceptionEvent` class and inspect its methods?

Comment: @emix I am getting error in this line $exception = $event->getException();

Comment: 1) open the class 2) notice there's no `getException` method, the error message is self explanatory 3) look for other methods 4) notice the `getThrowable` method 5) use `getThrowable` instead 6) read the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Symfony 4.4 the `getException` method was deprecated, and was removed in Symfony 5.

Use `getThrowable` instead.

---

- [Event Dispatcher documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener)